# select a row of matrix based on Date in R

Tags: r, function, select

I'm new in R.I have a small question. I want to select one row based on date. I write a function but it doesn't work.Here is my example.

Here my data sample:

```
 Example 
    Date A B 
  1 01/01/2000 0.6765442 1 
  2 01/01/2001 0.1374231 10 
  3 01/01/2002 0.6917205 0 
  4 01/01/2003 0.1440152 5 
  5 01/01/2004 0.1143759 8 
  6 01/01/2005 0.3379550 7 
  7 01/01/2006 0.4477631 9 
  8 01/01/2007 0.6164849 6 
  9 01/01/2008 0.1232872 8 
 10 01/01/2009 0.3511471 6
```

I tried using this code:

```
 test=function(Data,text)  { 
         for ( i in (1:col(Data))) 
              { 
              if (Data[i,1]=="text") 
                 { L=i 
                   R1=Data[L,] 
                   return(R1)  } 
                  }  }
```

Comment: You can select a row based on a date with `Example[Example$Date == '01/01/2000', ]` or you can use the function `subset` that reads a little better than the confusing looking brackets. `subset(Example, Date == '01/01/2000')`

Comment: @plafort yes but you should avoid using `subset` within a function...

Comment: Where in my comment is a function wrap suggested? @agstudy

Comment: @plafort No harms, I mean it is worth to mention it, since the OP is asking for wrapper function . That's said `subset` has better sugar syntax.

Comment: @KrollDU please remove extra comments from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **R-vectorized**  feature to subset data. No need to use a *for-loop* here. For example:

```
Data[Data$Date == "01/01/2001",]
##         Date         A  B
## 2 01/01/2001 0.1374231 10
```

Of course you can wrap this in a function:

```
subset_by_date <-
   function(date_txt,Data)  Data[Data$Date == date_txt,]
```

PS : in you function you have a typo error , you should use the text argument and not "text".

### update to check if col in data.frame before filtering

```
subset_by_date <-
   function(date_txt,Data,col="Date") {
          if (col  %in% colnames(Data))
             Data[Data[,col] == date_txt,]
   }
```

Comment: The function assumes that a column named `Date` exists, We can generalize with `f <- function(DF, date_txt, COL=Date) eval(substitute(DF[DF$COL == date_txt, ]))`

Comment: True, that is a better option. +1